# Expression of a sum of Hecke eigenvalues in terms of one Hecke eigenvalue

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, hecke-operators

Let $f$ be a modular form of an even weight $k$ over the modular group $SL_2(Z).$ Denote $\lambda_f(n)$ the $n$-th normalized Fourier coefficient of $f.$ I am doing some calculations and I am stack in finding the expression of the sum $\sum_{d|n} \lambda_f\left(\frac{n^2}{d^2}\right)$ in terms of $ \lambda_f(n)$ or $ \lambda_f(n)^2.$ Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Hecke relation, we get 
$$ \lambda_f(n)^2 =\sum_{d|n} \lambda_f\left(\frac{n^2}{d^2}\right).$$